# Python google api reading with urllib and json

Tags: python, json, google-api

My Code is very short but it is not working but in youtube videos it works

```
import urllib.request
import json

key = "AIzaSyCyTALBjNAEp-Vr5GkilEnLzH0y1Tw6SC4"
data = urllib.request.urlopen("www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=pewdiepie&key="+key).read()
subs = json.loads(data)['items'][0]["statistics"]['subscriberscount']
print(subs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create you own API key

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=pewdiepie&key=AIzaSyCyTALBjNAEp-Vr5GkilEnLzH0y1Tw6SC4

shows

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "YouTube Data API v3 has not been used in project 195563281908 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=195563281908 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "YouTube Data API v3 has not been used in project 195563281908 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=195563281908 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Here you can find how to create own API key:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started